# Atollic TS не видит файл библиотеки на Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: c, ubuntu, stm32

Хочу протестировать отладочную плату stm32f0Discovery и для этого нужно просто зажечь светодиод. На IAR или KEIL в Windows задача решается у меня без проблем.

Но в Atollic на Ubuntu 20.04 LTS чудеса да странности: при первом клике по Debug проект компилится, при повторном же выдается ошибка:

```
fatal error: stm32f0xx.h: No such file or directory main.c  /Test_3/code    line 1  C/C++ Problem
```

Код из main.c:

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_rcc.h"

//Define LED pins
#define GreenLED_Pin GPIO_Pin_9
#define LED_GPIO GPIOC

int main(void)
{
  //Create GPIO struct
  GPIO_InitTypeDef Gp; 
  
  //Enable clocks to GPIOC (output LEDs)
  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

  Gp.GPIO_Pin = GreenLED_Pin; //Set pins inside the struct
  Gp.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT; //Set GPIO pins as output
  Gp.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP; //Ensure output is push-pull vs open drain
  Gp.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL; //No internal pullup resistors required
  Gp.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_Level_1; //Set GPIO speed to lowest
  GPIO_Init(LED_GPIO, &Gp); //Assign struct to LED_GPIO

  GPIO_SetBits(LED_GPIO, GreenLED_Pin);

return 0;
}
```

Сам файл есть в проекте!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пути к файлу прописаны здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и здесь они прописались автоматически

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будьте добры помочь советом!

Прошу не минусовать вопрос без видимой на то причины.
Если есть замечания по вопросу, напишите в комментариях, и вопрос будет дополнен или изменен.

Comment: Вам удобно будет созвониться в discord? Скажем, часов в 5 по Москве.

Comment: Вы есть в телеграм?

Comment: Нет, но разве там есть демонстрация экрана и управление?

Comment: Что насчет zoom? Я мог бы продемонстрировать создание и отладку проекта по нему

Comment: Да, можно. 15 символов нужно...

Comment: Вы про ссылку для связи?

Comment: https://us05web.zoom.us/j/7476226277?pwd=M0g2a2g4MGNLSzhOdjhWQXkrUDN4dz09

Comment: Не дождался вас и ушёл.

Comment: Вы не ответили на предыдущий вопрос, я решил что связь отменяется :-) Поэтому на сайте не был.

Comment: Вам будет удобно завтра в период с 12:30 до 16:30 по мск или после 18 часов?

Comment: 15 символов - это минимальная длина комментария. Завтра можно после 18 в zoom.

Comment: Договорились. Спасибо!

Comment: Добрый день! У меня по основной работе завал. Так и не успел освободиться. В какое время еще с вами можно будет связаться завтра?

Comment: Можно сейчас....

Comment: К сожалению, все еще на работе. Мы можем перейти в личный чат?

Comment: https://vk.com/sdianov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно в разделе С++ General вообще ничего трогать не надо, все нужные настройки задаются в С/С++ Build → Settings. В Eclipse пути к заголовочным файлам для использования при сборке задаются на вкладке С/С++ Build → Settings → Tool Settings → C Compiler → Includes. А в Path and Symbols задаются дополнительные пути для парсера самого Eclipse. Это может быть нужно, когда используется особый(самосборный) тулчейн, у которого необычный набор встроенных инклюдов, о которых не знает Eclipse.

Comment: Я проверил по указанному пути. В вопросе дополнил картинкой. Только там нет includes...

Comment: На вид оно правильно прописано. Единственное, что несколько странно - использование синтаксиса `include ""` вместо `include <>` для включения внешнего заголовочного файла. А так должно работать. Лог сборки стоит приводить целиком.

Comment: Я уже и так и эдак менял. Не срабатывает. При чём весьма странная ситуация: при первом клике по дебагу проект компилится. При повторном дебаге как-раз и выдается та ошибка